# setting Separator on certain height from previous control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a vertical stack panel , my last control there is some `Label` and I want on a height 60 after the last control to show `Separator` any idea how to do so ?

Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want your separator *60 pixels after last control (Label)*? If so, you can put eg. empty `<StackPanel Height="60"/>` after your last label control, and before `Separator`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain your question a bit more?

You can add separator like this in a stackpanel

```
 <StackPanel Name="StackPanel1">
    <Button Height="23" Name="Button1">Button</Button>
    <Button Height="23" Name="Button2" Width="Auto">Button</Button>
    <Separator Height="5" Name="Separator1" Width="Auto" />
    <Button Height="23" Name="Button3" >Button</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

As shown above you can change height of any control